# SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor : throws org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException & javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am implementing SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. When i insert or update to data base  it throws following exception org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query errors.

spring-asyn-context.xml

```
<bean id="applicationEventMulticaster"
    class="org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster">
    <property name="taskExecutor" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error Details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you jump to a new thread, you no longer have an hibernate session.  You need to re-establish your session/EJBContext/PersistenceContext/Transaction context prior to executing your operation.  I could tell you which and how if you posted some code.

Comment: my problem is missing the @Override in onApplicationEvent() method.